# Why does the colorchooser from tkinter only run once in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, waffle-chart

I am trying to get 5 color inputs from the user and display them in blocks using waffle, but the colorchooser runs only once and the code is stuck after closing the colorchooser.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pywaffle import Waffle
from tkinter import colorchooser

colors_list = []
for i in range(1,6):
    color_code = colorchooser.askcolor(title ="Choose color"+str(i))
    colors_list.append(color_code[1])
    print(colors_list)
fig = plt.figure(
    FigureClass= Waffle,
    rows = 1, columns= 5,
    values = [1,1,1,1,1],
    colors=colors_list,
    title = {"label": "Home Color Scheme", "loc": "center", "size": 20}
)
plt.show()
```

I tried to ask the user using multiple variables and without using loops as well.

Comment: When I run the code the color chooser runs 5 times. Are you sure _this_ code only runs `colorchooser.askcolor` once?

Comment: Yes, it does for me. So I am guessing it's an issue with my compiler then.